# identityserver3 - can an access token issued by one id server be used with another id server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver3

I've been trying out IdentityServer3 and have watched the videos, followed through the online docs, downloaded the samples and I have got the samples all working fine.

I have set up two separate identity servers, one for securing a web api and one for securing an MVC app. I have done this rather than have one id server for both because the two applications are essentially for two different customers and only a few of the users will be in common.

However, I do want to be able to call the web api (api_A, idsvr_A) from the mvc app (mvc_B, idsvr_B) for some users (Single Sign On).

I'm finding that this works fine if I use the same idsvr at both ends but I thought that I should be able to have mvc_B get an access token from idsvr_B, add it to a request calling api_A and have idsvr_A act on the claims in the token?

I'm finding that idsvr_A does not understand(?) the token from idsvr_B and when I try to inspect the claims list on context.Principal in a breakpoint in api_A it is empty & the principal is not set to the identity from idsvr_B:

e.g. in a class deriving from ResourceAuthorizationManager, the context in the

CheckAccessAsync(ResourceAuthorizationContext context)

method ends up with an empty claims list on the context.Principal.

Is there something I need to do to translate claims from one idsvr to another? Or have I not set this up correctly? I thought that since the access token format is standard the tokens would be interchangeable between id servers?

I'm really asking for confirmation that this *should* work, before I do further debugging to make sure the token is being passed and received correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the two identity servers will have different issuer names and different signing certificates - so no - the web api will not accept both unless you add one validation middleware for each identityserver.

It is uncommon for an API to trust multiple issuers but technically possible.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. Yes the two id servers would have different issuer names & certificates. I was thinking  that this case is like the external authentication from Google, Facebook etc but in this case the external provider is just another IdentityServer3? Would you have time to elaborate on your suggestion to add validation middleware for each identity server please?

Comment: Further to my last comment, would it be meaningful or allowed to have multiple calls in the api's Startup.cs file to app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(), each one specifying a different Authority (all of which are trusted by the api)? If so, would app.UseResourceAuthorization(...) still work?

Comment: The external providers approach only works for web browser based flows. If thats what you use - that is the recommended architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will explore that option. I really appreciate all your work providing IdentityServer and your excellent videos.